# Classifying regions of Van der Waal like gas

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, stability

> Given the equation of state
>   $$p+a\left(\frac{N}{V}\right)=\frac{Nk_BT}{V-bN} \tag 1$$
>   Taking into account of the fact that a realistic model requires $p \geq 0, V \geq Nb, N>0$ classify the solutions of the equation of state as a function of temperature.

My attempt is that

$$\left[p+a\left(\frac{N}{V}\right)\right]\left[\frac{V-bN}{V} \right]=\frac{Nk_BT}{V} $$
Let $n=\frac{N}{V}$,

$$\left[p+an\right]\left[1-bn \right]=nk_BT$$

$$p+an-pbn-abn^2=nk_BT$$

Let $\tilde{n}=\sqrt{ab}n$, $\tilde{n}^2=abn^2$,

$$\tilde{n}^2+\left(p\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}-\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\right)\tilde{n}-p+\frac{k_BT}{\sqrt{ab}}=0$$

Let $\tilde{p}=\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}p$,

$$\tilde{n}^2+\left(\tilde{p}-\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\right)\tilde{n}-\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}p+\frac{k_BT}{\sqrt{ab}}=0$$

Let $\tilde{t}=\frac{k_BT}{\sqrt{ab}}$,

$$\tilde{n}^2+\left(\tilde{p}-\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\right)\tilde{n}-\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}p+\tilde{t}=0$$

Now the discriminant is $b^2-4ac$ so

$$\left(\tilde{p}-\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} \right)^2+4\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}p-4\tilde{t}$$

$$\tilde{p}^2-2\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\tilde{p}+\frac{a}{b} +4\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}p-4\tilde{t}$$

$$\left(\tilde{p}+\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} \right)^2=4\tilde{t}$$

so ignoring the negative time solution we have

$$\tilde{p}=-\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} +2\sqrt{\tilde{t}}$$

but I don't see what Im meant to be doing next.

> After I that I need to show that there is a region of the $T-V^{-1}$ plane where this equation of state is not thermodynamically stable and determine the boundary of this region.

I know that for stability we need that

$$\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V} \right)_{T,N} \leq 0$$

but I dont see how this is usable in the current context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you can directly write $p$ as a function of $V$ without solving a quadratic equation:

$$ p = \frac{N k_B T}{V- N b } - a \frac{N}{V} $$

Then you take a look at the interesting points

$$\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V}\right)_{T,N} = 0 $$

The solutions to this equation tell you where the [bulk modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus) (or its inverse, the [compressibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressibility)) might change the sign. That's how you can use this criterion to determine the boundaries of unstable regions.

EDIT: If I am not [mistaken](http://www.wolframalpha.com), the equation above has solutions

$$ \vartheta_\pm = b \frac{1}{1\pm \sqrt{\frac{k_B T}{a}}} =  b \frac{1}{1\pm \sqrt{t}}$$,

with $\vartheta = V/N$ and the reduced temperature $t=T k_B /a  $. In terms of this reduced variable and $v = \vartheta / b$ we can write

$$ \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial \vartheta}\right)_{T,N} = \frac{a}{b^2} \left(\frac{1}{v^2}- \frac{t}{(v-1)^2} \right) \overset{!}{\leq} 0$$

So you know the critical points where the sign might change and you know the equation for checking which sign is present. The only thing you have left to do is check which sign is present in which region along the $\vartheta$ axis. This is only math left to do.. Since you know the sign along the  $\vartheta$ axis you will automatically know the sign along the $\vartheta^{-1}$ axis.

Comment: Could you expand on your last sentence please? (I am only familiar with compressibility). Ive solved the second equation but got $V=\frac{2abN \pm \sqrt{4k_BTa}bN}{2(a-k_BT)}$

Comment: How can we do this in the $T-V^{-1}$ plane?

Comment: How did you know that the sign change is the criterion of this? I can find no mention of it my notes

Comment: Imagine you have gas whose pressure increases when you extend its volume. You could build a perpetual motion machine with this ;) That's why you expect this derivative to be negative. I will let you try a little bit and extend my answer a little bit later if you don't mind. A hint: it may also be useful to think about the temperature up to which your solution is really a solution. This will give you a critical temperature. Usually its easier to work with reduced quantities.

Comment: So $\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial \vartheta}\right)_{T,N}  {\leq} 0 \iff  \left(\frac{1}{v^2}- \frac{t}{(v-1)^2} \right) \leq 0 \iff  (-\frac{1}{v}+\frac{1}{v^2}) \leq t$ So if this is true stable if not unstable. I cannot see how this answers both parts though

Comment: I added some additional comment but there is not much left to say. You can do the math on your own I think :P

Comment: What I can offer you is to check if your result is correct :)

Comment: Ok I will do this as soon as I can